# Open sets of integral schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

The following is the definition of integral scheme as mentioned [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01OJ)

Let $X$ be a scheme. We say $X$ is integral if it is nonempty and for every nonempty affine open $\operatorname{Spec}(R)=U \subset X$ the ring $R$ is an integral domain.

How do I show that for **any open set** $U$, $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is an integral domain?

Comment: Read Qing Liu, "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves". section 2.4.3. It may seems that his definition is different and his starting point is not what you want but if you pay close attention your answer lies basically in part (c) of Prop. 4.18.

Answer (score 2):

First, $X$ is irreducible: if not, then I could find two nonempty disjoint affine opens and the coordinate ring of their union would not be a domain. For all affine open $U \subseteq X$, then, $\mathscr O(U)$ injects into its localization $R(X)$, the function field of $X$. Hence the same is true for arbitrary open $U$.

Answer (score 2):

You can write $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ where $U_i$ is non empty affine and open. Let $f,g\in O_X(U)$ such that $fg=0$. Denote by $f_i$ the restriction of $f$ to $U_i$, you have $f_ig_i=0$, this implies that $f_i=0$ or $g_i=0$. Lemma 27.3.4 of your reference shows that $X$ is irreducible and reduced, this implies that $U_i$ is dense, suppose $f_i=0$, $\{f(x)=0\subset X\}$ is a closed subset which contains the dense subset $U_i$ so it is $X$.

Comment: I think your last sentence is false if $X$ is non-reduced.

Comment: @paf It looks true to me, could you specify which claim exactly you think is false ($X$ is irreducible, $U_i $ is dense, something else?)

Comment: Exactly, it's the implication "closed subset $V$ containing a dense subset $\Rightarrow$ $V=X$". Indeed, it only means that the underlying topological spaces are the same but if $X$ isn't reduced, you can't conclude that $V=X$ scheme-theoretically ($f$ may be nilpotent on $X$).

Comment: In fact, using the OP's definition, we can prove that all local rings are reduced, hence $X$ is reduced and your argument becomes correct.

Comment: 27.3.4 quote here says that a scheme is integral if and only if it is irreducible and reduced,...

Comment: @paf, Tsemo Yeah, there are a bunch of ways to complete this. You can also just use the fact that $V|_{U_i}$ is the empty scheme, so $f$ is $0$ on $U_i$ (since $U_i$ is integral whence reduced) and so $f$ is $0$ on $U$. It just depends on taste really, I guess.